# Xamarin Forms Custom Composite Control for Picker with Filter

Tags: xamarin.forms, filter, controls, customization, picker

I am creating a custom composite component with an entry field and a list and I am having problems figuring out how to set up the bindable properties to display the items in the list. The purpose of the component is to be a filterable picker for lists that have hundreds or thousands of items. The idea is that this will control will be similar to the modal popup of a picker, but with a filter above the list. I can do this on a page, but am having difficulty doing this as a re-usable custom control with bindable properties. Here is what it looks like on a page:

[image: Picture of FilterPicker modal popup]

To reduce the complexity I was planning on the component just being what you see in the modal popup, rather than having the two parts of the picker control--the entry-like part that you see on the page as well as the modal popup. So the control XAML is just for the modal popup and is fairly simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
      xmlns:localeffects="clr-namespace:ReceivingApp.Effects"
      xmlns:localcontrols="clr-namespace:ReceivingApp.Controls"
      x:Class="ReceivingApp.Controls.FilterPicker"
      RowSpacing="0"
      ColumnSpacing="0">
      
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="PlaceholderLabel" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

    <!-- filter -->
    <localcontrols:PancakeEntry x:Name="FilterEntry" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,8"  />

    <!-- list --> 
    <yummy:PancakeView Grid.Row="2"
                       BackgroundColor="#F9F9F9"
                       Margin="0,0,0,16"
                       Padding="8, 2, 8, 2"
                       BorderColor="#D3D3D3"
                       BorderThickness="1"
                       CornerRadius="8"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       >
        <ListView x:Name="ListPicker" 
                  Margin="0,12"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                  SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label x:Name="LabelDisplayItem" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </yummy:PancakeView>
    
    <Button Text="CANCEL" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="100" Command="{Binding FilterPickerCancelCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that there is a ListView in the control and I need to set its ItemsSource BindableProperty to that of the ItemsSource BindableProperty of the control, which is fine. But how do I also include a BindableProperty that is the field to display in the ListView--the LabelDisplayItem.Text? There will only be one field displayed and it is in the context of the object that is the list of objects displayed by the ListView.

Here is the code-behind that doesn't work that shows what I am trying to do with the ItemsSource and DisplayField BindableProperties.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ReceivingApp.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class FilterPicker : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty DisplayFieldProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DisplayField)
                , typeof(string)
                , typeof(FilterPicker)
                , default(string)
                , BindingMode.OneWay);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource)
               , typeof(IEnumerable)
               , typeof(FilterPicker)
               , default(IEnumerable)
               , BindingMode.TwoWay);

        // Other BindableProperties go here such as PlaceholderProperty     

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public string DisplayField
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DisplayFieldProperty);
            set => SetValue(DisplayFieldProperty, value);
        }

        // Other properties here

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == DisplayFieldProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                //how to get the appropriate context to set the LabelDisplayItem?
                LabelDisplayItem.Text = [bind this to the display field]
            }

            else if (propertyName == ItemsSourceProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                ListPicker.ItemsSource = ItemsSource;
            }
        }
        
        // Other code to use Linq to filter the values of the List -- resetting the ItemSource to the filtered list.

    }
}
```

It is no problem to do this on an individual page because I know the object in the ListView that I am working with and can bind to the appropriate field of the object to display it. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this as a re-usable control.

Thoughts and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One technique for solving such problems, is to pass in to the custom control an `Action` that can do what you need.

Also, instead of attempting to manipulate a UI item directly, manipulate its model.

Suppose the "consumer" (of your custom control) has a model list `List<MyModel> Models;`.
And MyModel has a string that is bound to the UI item to be changed:

```cs
public class MyModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string MyString
    {
        get => _myString;
        set { _myString = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string _myString;

    public Action<string> GetActionThatSetsMyString()
    {
        return (value) => MyString = value;
    }
}
```

Then if, in the consumer, this is the model to be changed:
`MyModel model = Models[i];`

You could set a property on custom control, to the needed action:

```cs
public Action<string> UseChangedString { get; set; }
...
myControl.UseChangedString = model.GetActionThatSetsMyString();
...
// When you have a new value for string:
UseChangedString(newValue);
```